# Flex RemoteObject Intermittently Failing to Invoke CFC

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, coldfusion, cfc

I have a Flex app that uses Flash Remoting and the RemoteObject to pull data from a ColdFusion CFC.  About 75% of the time it works, but the other times I get a message using Charles (a debugging tool) that says faultString = "Unable to Invoke CFC".  FaultCode = "Server.Processing".

Here's my RemoteObject:

```
<mx:RemoteObject id="carsSvc" destination="ColdFusion" source="ca.sqmIDash.cfc.sqmIdash">
   <mx:method name="getCARs" result="resultHandler(event)"/>
</mx:RemoteObject>
```

The server set up on our web farm is to use load balancing.  I'm not sure if this is causing the problem or not.  Probably not, but it's a thought.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Can you get access to the log files of the server(s) and cross check a time you recieved the error?   There might be an exception in the log files for the ca.sqmIDash.cfc.sqmIdas CFC that might give you a better idea of the error.   Worth checking that every server on the webfarm can resolve the ca.sqmIDash.cfc.sqmIdas through remoting... seen a few issues in Load Balancer situations where not all servers had same settings.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're having server issues completely independent of Flex.  I'd look into the load balancer and/or what the machine re doing that 25% of the time you're receiving the error.

I'd also add some error checking on the server to e-mail you the relevant errors.  ( Perhaps in the onError Application.cfc )  That may help you diagnose if there is a bug in your server side code.

I do not see a RemoteObject in your question, even though you have a line that says "here is my RemoteObject"